# get the month f the financial year in json

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the selectbox with the option 2019-2020,2020-2021.I I choose the financial year 2019-2020 I want to display the month as `{"month":["Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec","Jan","Feb","Mar"]}`.

If I choose the financial year 2020-2021 I want to display the month `{"month":["Apr","May"]}`.

Is it possible to get the json based on selected financial year. can I get the json response in select option onclick

```js
$('.financialyear').change(function(){
 console.log($('.financialyear').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="financialyear" >
 <option>2019-2020</option>
 <option>2020-2021</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why `{"month":["Apr","May"]}` ?

Comment: @0stone0 Because we're still in May 2020 and don't have a time machine yet ;)

Comment: _"Is it possible..."_ - Yes. _"can I get..."_ - There's no `click` event for `<option>`s

Comment: Is the question about the function to convert towards the desired JS object, or is the question about the change event not working?

Comment: Still don't quite understand why `'19-'20` shows `apr...mar` but `'20-'21` shows only `apr-may` ?

Comment: @0stone0 The fiscal year 2019-2020 is already over (according to the definition of OP). The current one (2020-2021) is only partly over, namely April and May.

Comment: you can try to use value attribute of the option elements. You could populate them with an array of possible options (months) which is later used in another drop down

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```js
    var months = [ "Jan","Feb","Mar", "Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec" ];
    var starting_month = "Apr";
    var current_year = new Date().getFullYear().toString();
    var current_month = months[ new Date().getMonth() ];

    $('.financialyear').change(function(){
      console.clear();
      
      var value = $('.financialyear').val();
      var start_year = value.split('-')[0];
      var index = months.indexOf( starting_month );
      var count = 0;
      var financial_months = [];

      while( count < 12 ) {
        financial_months.push( months[index] );

        if ( current_year === start_year && current_month === months[index] ) {
          break;
        }
        index++;

        if ( index === months.length ) {
          index = 0;
        }
        count++;
      }
      console.log( { months: financial_months } );
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <select class="financialyear" >
     <option value="2019-2020">2019-2020</option>
     <option value="2020-2021">2020-2021</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Quite a complicated way to get the `start_year` (it's already in `value`) and how you determine the months (`Array.prototype.slice()`) but it works.